# Java Script redirect approcach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script code where I try to redirect to a different url. Also I need to pass certain information during the redirect. So, my code looks like this:

```
function testRedirectCode(){

 var dataToBePassed = "abc";

 var url="https://anydomain.com/hello.aspx";
 var form=$('<form action="'+url+'"
     method="post">'+'<input type="text" name="srcUrl" value="http://myapplication.com/helloPage" />'
     +'<input type="text" name="data" value="'+dataToBePassed+'" />'
     +'</form>');
     $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

My 2 problems:

1) Is there a more clean way of writing the src url than hardcoding i.e. identify the current url and pass the same in this value.

2) I see that on my button click I am able to get redirected on the new page but the problem is that instantaneously I am again redirected to my srcUrl.

Anyway of getting past this?

Thanks in advance
-Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! you can identify the current url without hardcoding it

To get the current url

```html
<script>

var url =window.location.href;
console.log(url);

var protocol =location.protocol; //http or https

var baseUrl =location.hostname; //myapplication.com

var path =location.pathname; //login

var urlSrc =protocol +'//' +baseUrl+ '/'+path
console.log(urlSrc);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel... it helps for resolving the prblem 1.

Comment: I have 2 problems here... for 1st problem, I can accept your answer..any idea on the 2nd problem? Cheers, Vivek

Comment: Do you have this same exact code on that same page you were redirected to?

Comment: If you have the same exact code in that page, you will be redirected because your code will automatically run and submit the form again.  You can tie submit action to an onclick event

Comment: The page that I am redirecting to is a different application not owned by me. So, there is no way of knowing if that's a possibility.

Comment: It's possible that the application has a logic implemented to redirect back to referring page. A good example is, if your request does not pass validation checks